# C++ console application with While operator

Tags: c++

I need help about a problem I need to solve. I have tried to run it on Code Blocks, but the compiler displays an error (*Execution of 'mingw32-g++.exe   -c C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\main.cpp -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\main.o' in 'C:\Windows\system32' failed*), so I am asking about some code correction (if needed) here instead:

> Create a c++ console application, which enters a random number of values until 0 is entered, and displays the biggest of all uneven numbers [entered].

The solution has to be simple and include nothing more complicated than `if` and `while`.
Just to make sure you understand I will give an example:
*You enter in console :
2 7 9 4 6 10 **0***

*It displays:**9***.
**This is an example of how the program should work, not how it works with my code in reality!**
Here is what I have tried to do by now:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, max;
    cout<<"insert number here:";
    cin>>a; //Inserting first "a" so that I can save max a value of first a and compare it to the next entered values
    if (a%2!=0)max=a;
    while(a!=0)
    {
        cin>>a;
        if(a%2!=0 && a>max)max=a;
    }
    cout<<max;
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:**I am more interested in finding the solution for this problem than fixing the Code Blocks error, but I will be happy if help can be provided for both problems!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144181/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-halachev-c-console-application-with-while-ope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first number you enter is even, `max` will be left uninitialized and the program will work incorrectly

There are several ways of fixing this problem:

1. Initializing `max` manually to a value that is guaranteed to be less than all of the input numbers (e.g. if it is guaranteed that all numbers are positive, initialize `max` with -1)
2. Checking a bool flag to understand when an odd number was inputed
   e.g.

   ```
   #include<iostream>
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
       bool foundodd = true;
       int max = 0;
       int a = 0;
       while (cin >> a && a != 0)
       {
           if (a % 2)
           {
               if (foundodd)
               {
                   if (a > max)
                   {
                       max = a;
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   max = a;
                   foundodd = true;
               }
           }
       }
       cout << max;
   }
   ```
3. Input the first even numbers until you reach an odd, then initialize `max` with the first odd

   ```
   #include<iostream>
   using namespace std;
   int main()
    {
       int a = 0, max = 0;
       while (cin >> a && a % 2 == 0)
       {

       }
       max = a;
       while (a != 0)
       {
           cin >> a;
           if (a % 2 && a > max)
           {
               max = a;
           }
       }  
      cout<<max;
      return 0;
   }
   ```

Your algorithm is correct, your only problem is the uninitialized `max`

Comment: Yes, Scheff has already suggested the first way, but I think there must be another, smarter one, which does not require me to know the lowest int value nor the bool check (I haven't studied this, so I cannot use it at school). Thank you for your attention and attempt to solve this problem. If you think of another way of initialising max, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: @DanielHalachev I added a new way, you can input the even numbers at the beginning, please check the post

Comment: If I understood correctly, then I must know which numbers I am going to insert? In this case, we are not solving the problem correctly as the program is supposed to deal with random entered and unlimited in count numbers. Please, feel free to correct me if I have interpretated your answer in a wrong way. I guess that my teacher didn't insist on methods different from setting max to the lowest value of the int type. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @DanielHalachev No, you do not need to know the numbers. This is what my program does:
First, it inputs all even numbers there are in the beginning, because you do not need them. The first while loop ends when the input number is odd. Then the max value is initialized with that number and the loop proceeds nowmally

Comment: Lol, yes, but...I...am so confused! It works so well...but...I guess you will have to give an example as I just cannot get the code! Of course, if you are so generous to. I guess I must be very dumb not to understand what the code does! Thank you!

Comment: Now, after thinking I finally got it! Very smart written!

Comment: The entire `foundodd` machinery in your first code snippet is unnecessary noise. You already initialized `max` to zero (although `INT_MIN` is the correct value), so you can unconditionally write `if ( a > max ) max = a;`. It makes no difference, whether this is the first test or not.

Comment: The choice of `INT_MIN` adds no restrictions. You opted to choose `int` as the data type, so *you* restricted the acceptable range yourself. If you really want a solution, that works regardless of data type, use `std::numeric_limits`. There is no reason anyone would want to write code like that.

Comment: Since you were too lazy to look it up, here is the hyperlink: [std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). There is no reason, ever, to employ your clumsy implementation using a flag.

Comment: This question isn't about Python. It's tagged [tag:c++], and in C++ you would simply use `std::numeric_limits` to cover **all** use cases. Then again, your profile tells me, that you are *"yet another noob"*, so maybe you wouldn't even understand, if I literally spelled it out for you.

Comment: If you are using a user-defined data type for your numbers (which you aren't), simply use `std::numeric_limits` (wait... have I not recommended this **two** times already?). If your data type doesn't come with the required specialization, ask the author for one. If it is yours, implement the appropriate specialization yourself. Nothing in the first comment indicates a mathematically correct solution either. If it did, you *could* use a flag, but don't branch on it every time through your loop. Simply set it unconditionally, whenever updating `max`.